# How can i perform binary negation on this number to get an answer

Tags: binary, negation

I am learning binary code and I can't get my head around binary negation. I have an example and was hoping someone could walk me through how to answer this question.

Perform binary negation on this binary number. -11011
The answer is 11100101 but I'm not sure how to show the breakdown of how this answer is achieved.

Comment: Write the original number as 00011011. Now have a go.

Comment: omg im so stupid. so write out the number to include 8 bits/ digits and then just flip the 0's to 1's and vice versa? That definitely makes a lot of sense now. thankyou

Comment: Remember to add 1 at the end for 2's complement.

Comment: And, not stupid. It's confusing when all of the bits aren't accounted for.